# bxslider showing empty space when in infinite loop

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have added a bxslider in my project this way:
jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideWidth: 340,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 0,
            infiniteLoop: true
        });
```

HTML Part:

```
<div style="width:100%;float: left; position: relative; bottom: 17px;">
    <ul class="bxslider" id="slider1" >
        <li style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;width:340px !important;">
<img src="/Content/images/home.png" alt="home" width="340"height="239" />
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;width:340px !important;">
<img src="/Content/images/home1.png" alt="home1" width="340"height="239" />
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;width:340px !important;">
<img src="/Content/images/home2.png" alt="home2" width="340"height="239" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As we click on the next button, we see the images moving in the slider 1 by 1. When all the images of the slider get finished, it starts rotating again from the first image - in this case we see a small "empty area" and after that the first image. We want a smooth loop to work circularly without any empty space seen.

The link of the above problem mentioned is

http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/simplehtml/testing/testing.html

Can anyone tell me the solution of this ?It will be greatly appreciable

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Is it going through all the slides correctly and can you verify all images are showing? Could it be a missing image?

Comment: Yes, it is going through all the slides correctly. I see the 1st image just after the 3rd image but with a gap coming in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Using `backface-visibility: hidden` for `li` tag elements worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use 'ticker'.  Like so:

```
$( '.bxslider' ).bxSlider( {
      pager: false,
      slideMargin: 30,
      controls: false,
      speed: 50000,
      useCSS: false,
      ticker: true,
      tickerHover: true,
      slideWidth: 300,
      responsive: false,
      minSlides: 2,
      maxSlides: 100,
  } );
```

This will create the effect of a news ticker or continuous feed left to right.  If this does not work, you have something wrong with your CSS.  I do not have any styles written around my HTML for this.  Only these bxslider settings here in the jQuery.